# Delete folder recursively from a specified path, conditionally

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to delete a folder with its contents recursively from a specific path under a cmd file. I don't want to delete other folders in the same folder as the path. I don't know in advance which folder has the folder I want to delete.

I did it with files but not with folders. Here i paste my code:

```
IF exist "\\PC1\temp\" (
rd "\\PC1\temp\"%dl% /s /q
ECHO Folder deleted successfully in PC1
) ELSE (echo PC1 is not connected)
```

NOTE: `"%dl` is a variable with the name of the folder to be deleted typed before from the user.

But if the folder exists inside another folder (for example: \PC1\temp\test) the folder can´t be deleted even if I use the `/s` property.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

Here is a DOS/CMD one-liner that will delete only the folder in the current directory that contains the subfolder "hello" in it:

```
for /d %d in (*) do if exist "%d\hello\." echo y | rd /s /q "%d"
```

NOTE: If you run this from a batch file you must change `%d` to `%%d` in all places.

#### Background on rd

You use the "/s" switch for rd command, combined with feeding a "y" to the command if you don't want to be prompted. Be warned that this command is very dangerous (think rm -rf in unix):

```
echo y | rd /s /q "\\PC1\temp\%dl%"
```

You don't have to check if the folder exists - just run it either way - it'll fail silently if it doesn't exist and succeed silently if it does.

Comment: I thought the /q was to delete without be prompted. Is not? What about if the target folder is inside another folder? The /s should delete recursively, no? Thanks for replying

Comment: /q is for quiet - you specified that in your original question. Using /q means you don't need to test if the folder exists before deleting it - the result will be the same either way. The /s deletes the folder specified and any sub folders and files. In your case \\PC1\temp will still exist, but \\PC1\temp\%dl% will not. If %dl% does not evaluate to anything, then \\PC1\temp *will* be removed, so be careful about that.

Comment: Yes but the problem is when the folder I want to delete is inside another folder from the specified path. For example, I want to delete the folder hello, and I specify the path PC1\temp to search but hello is in PC1\temp\test\hello, Do you know what I mean? Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that there is a sub-folder you want to delete but you don't know which folder it is in? So like this: PC1\temp\test1\ ... test999\ where "hello" folder is in PC1\temp\test522? Is the problem that you don't know where the hello folder is? Do you want to delete all the "test1 - test999" folders or only the one where hello is located?

Comment: Yes exactly, I want to delete hello folder but I don't know in which subfolder it is.

Comment: I just updated the answer with code that deletes the subfolder AND all its contents INCLUDING the `hello` folder. If you don't want to delete the subfolder and just want to delete the hello folder, let me know if you can't figure that out and I'll update the answer.